# Filter an ArrayList by the first syllable

Tags: android, arraylist

Well, I have a game that shows you a pic and four buttons with alternatives and I need to filter these alternatives by the syllable like Button1 = Cat, Button2 = Car, Button3...
This is my ArrayList from de database class:

```
Integer[] imagens = {
            R.drawable.urso,
            R.drawable.girafa,
            R.drawable.cachorro,
            R.drawable.casa,
            R.drawable.carro,
            R.drawable.guitarra,
           R.drawable.terra,
            R.drawable.gato,
            R.drawable.cavalo,
            R.drawable.leao,
            R.drawable.jacare,
            R.drawable.elefante,
           R.drawable.bola

    };

    String[] enAlternativas = {

       "bear",
       "giraffe",
        "dog",
        "house",
       "car",
       "guitar",
       "earth",
        "cat",
        "horse",
        "lion",
        "alligator",
        "elephant",
       "ball"

};
```

I have  a class called List where there is 2 objects: String nome and int imagem, so my array list in the GameActivity is like this `List<List> lista;`

And I add the objects from the database class with this line of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < new bdGame().alternativas.length; i++) {

            lista.add(new Lista(new bdGame().alternativas[i], new bdGame().imagens[i]));

        }
```

So, the returning to the main question. How can I filter these buttons to show the options "Car", "Cat"... and whatever that starts with "Ca".
 [image]

Obs: If you need some more information tell me.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you prefer to filter your data exactly by syllable or by first symbols only, like in context search? In first case, I think, you need any library which can parse words in your language, in 2nd - you can try regular expressions.

Comment: Since you are using the integer value of the resource (which is unique) I would suggest using a `HashMap`. It will be easier then trying to synchronize two arrays.

Comment: It has to be by syllable because it's for help to literate children with intellectual disabilities.

Comment: @OllieSmith To make it clear, Are you using a `SQLiteOpenHelper` as your Database?

Comment: No, it's just the class called bdGame.class.

Comment: "Car" is the only syllable in "Car", there is no such syllable as "Ca" there...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I'm brazilian.